# Should I get the Dungeon Master's Guide, the Player's Handbook, or the Monster Manual?

Tags: dnd-5e, books

So I'm a fairly new player in the game Dungeons & Dragons (D&D). I'm known about the game/played a very loose version of the game a little over a year ago and I started getting serious about ten-eleven months ago. Currently, I am still learning about the game, its concepts, and how to play. Something I would love to try is DMing. But there are a few problems with that:

1. I'm still not a master at the game and I'm still learning
2. I'm not sure if I have all the resources.

So I'm asking you guys! What would be the most important to get for an inspiring world builder and D&D player? The Dungeon Master's Guide, the Player Handbook, or the Monster Manual? I currently have some beginner level stuff that just teaches you the basics, but what if I want to go deeper?

Comment: Your question is a bit subjective as it seems you're inquiring about of those 3, which do you need (most)? I recommend that you clarify what kind of game you want to play (campaign, sandbox style, one-shot, etc.) and then clarify what resources you currently have already (online Basics rules, anything else).

Answer (score 6):

### The Player's Handbook

Although this question is too subjective for SE, there are some arguments to why the PHB is the best option of the three core rulebooks. The overriding reason is that *it is all you need to play*.

The adventuring, combat, and spellcasting chapters cover the core rules of the game in roughly 30 pages (spell descriptions excluded). These are the most important chapters of the game, because they are the general rules governing all things.

The PHB supplies player options, which are required to play the game, and a few monsters - mostly animals - are available in the back of the book as a mini-Monster Manual.

In contrast to the PHB, the DMG provides optional rules and guidelines for DMs to craft intricate and interesting worlds, but none of the base rules and the MM provides more monsters (and nothing but). Clearly, the PHB is the only one of the three core rulebooks that stands on its own.